# How to remove the caption label and number (say, "Figure #" ) from one specific figure in revtex4 document of Latex?

Tags: labels, floats

I am preparing a report in `revtex4` document of Latex. Can someone please help me to remove the figure label and number of one specific figure in my document?

I tried and successfully did using the `\usepackage{caption}`, but it then led all my figure captions to center hanging indentation. Therefore, I need an alternative to do the same.

My code goes as:

```
\documentclass[preprint,aps,prb,floatfix]{revtex4}
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphics}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
%\usepackage{caption}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{Figure \thefigure}
\makeatother
 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{centering}
    %\captionsetup{labelformat=empty,labelsep=none}
    \includegraphics[width=8.5cm, height=4.75cm, keepaspectratio]{xxx.ps}
    \caption{xxxx}
    \label{xxx}
    \end{centering}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the caption text without the prefix "Figure #", simply don't use a caption. You can add the text as normal text below the image.

Unrelated to your question, but `\centering` is a macro and not an environment.

```
\documentclass[preprint,aps,prb,floatfix]{revtex4}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
%\usepackage{caption}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{Figure \thefigure}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=8.5cm, height=4.75cm, keepaspectratio]{example-image}
    
    xxxx
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz for the solution as well as correcting my mistake.

Comment: @Madhusmita You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The `revtex4` class is obsolete and quite likely you're supposed to use `revtex4-2` instead.

In any case, `caption` should not be used, because it takes over RevTeX’s style (and is generally incompatible with the class).

You don't need to use `\caption`, and you need not do `\centering`, because it's applied automatically.

Other points to note:

1. `epsfig` should not be used
2. load `graphicx` and not `graphics`; no `dvips` option should be added
3. redefine `\figurename` and not `\fnum@figure`; the copy editor will be happier (and probably remove the redefinition anyway)

```
\documentclass[preprint,aps,prb,floatfix]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\includegraphics[width=8.5cm, height=4.75cm, keepaspectratio]{example-image}

Some explanations about the figure.

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]